# Convergence in probability (asymptotic notation) result

Tags: self-study, convergence, asymptotics

Let $h=h_n$ be a sequence of numbers such that $h_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\mu$ be a real constant and $f$ be some probability density function. I was wondering if the following equality holds:

$$\frac{h^2 \mu f(x)+o_p(h^2)}{f(x)+o_p(1)}=h^2 \mu + o_p(h^2), \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

where $o_p$ denotes the ["small oh"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Small_O:_convergence_in_probability) asymptotic notation related to convergence in probability.

It seems correct to me, but I am unable to show it (rigorously).

Can you give me some advices?

Thank you in advance!

> **1st Attempt**

We have

$$\frac{h^2 \mu f(x)+o_p(h^2)}{f(x)+o_p(1)}
=\frac{h^2 \mu f(x)}{f(x)+o_p(1)}+
\frac{o_p(h^2)}{f(x)+o_p(1)}
=\frac{h^2 \mu}{1+o_p(1)}+
\frac{o_p(h^2)}{1+o_p(1)},$$

where the last equality was obtained by multipliying each term of the equation by $f(x)/f(x)$. One can think each of the terms of the R.H.S of the last equation as geometric series. Write

$$\frac{h^2 \mu}{1+o_p(1)}=h^2 \mu-h^2 \mu o_p(1)- h^2 \mu o_p(1)^2-\cdots=h^2 \mu+o_p(h^2)$$
$$\frac{o_p(h^2)}{1+o_p(1)}=o_p(h^2)-o_p(h^2)o_p(1)- o_p(h^2) o_p(1)^2-\cdots=o_p(h^2)$$

The sum of these term is then $h^2 \mu+o_p(h^2)$ as desired.

Comment: What is the interpretation of the equality $(=)$ sign here? That as $n \to \infty$ the left-hand side behaves as the right hand side?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes. When $n$ goes to infinity, there is a term which does not depend on $n$, and a term which vanishes at a certain (stochastic) order in the sense of the convergence in probability. This result would be easy to show if the denominator of the L.H.S. were only $f(x)$. But the convergent term $O_p(1)$ turns the situation more complicated.

Comment: Is this $o_p(1)$ or $O_p(1)$ after all?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos It is $o_p(1)$ actually. Clearly, if $X_n=o_p(1)$ it is also $O_p(1)$.